Invocar dato de la tabla de dato filtrado por ultima fecha y numero de unidad JAVA
Estoy haciendo una base de datos para carga de combustible.

Quiero invocar el OdometroActual de la ultima carga filtrado por el numero de unidad y la ultima fecha de carga para despues, depositarlo en el OdometroAnterior en la nueva carga de combustible.

Tengo problemas programando el PreparedStatement para buscar el dato y me manda este error:

Les agradeceria que me ayudaran con esto, apenas aprendi a conectarme con bases de datos en esta semana, llevo rato buscando como acomodar mi codigo pero no he dado con la solucion.
Saludos.

Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera medalla! El codigo, siempre como texto.. es muy dificil ayudarte sino... tenes un error en el query busqueda2... y aparte de eso, donde tenes el problema?? en ese codigo, no se ve eso que dice tu error

¡Bienvenido a Stack Overflow en español! Te invito a hacer el [tour]. Por favor no publiques código o mensajes de error/trazas de pila en imágenes, publica directamente el texto del código, el texto de los errores y los stack traces. Esto hace que sea menos complicado, para quien quiera ayudarte, investigar sobre el tema y hacer sus propias pruebas/adaptaciones al código, al escribir una respuesta y de esa forma aumenta tus posibilidades de encontrar la ayuda que buscas. Un saludo.

This question is similar to: Error al tratar de eliminar un registro en la base de datos desde Java. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.
